Mui-x Line Chart sliding animation
In my chart, when the number of series reaches 10, I remove the first element of my array and continue working with an array of 10 elements. However, the animation in the chart happens on both the x and y axes. Is it possible to make the animation shift only along the x-axis?
Stackblitz demo
export default function BasicLineChart() {
  const [series, setSeries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeries((prev) => {
        const newData = Math.random() * 25;
        let newSeries = [...prev];
        newSeries = [...prev, newData];
        if (newSeries.length > 10) {
          newSeries.shift();
        }
        return newSeries;
      });
    }, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [series]);

  return (
    <LineChart
      series={[
        {
          data: series,
        },
      ]}
      width={500}
      height={300}
    />
  );
}


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].
